# Nginx, Flask, Gunicorn 502 Error

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm still pretty new with Flask/Nginx/Gunicorn as this is only my second site using the combination. I created a website based off of Miguel Grinberg's [tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) so my file structure is exactly the same as in this tutorial.

In my previous Flask app, my app was in a single file called `app.py` so when I used Gunicorn I just called 
`gunicorn app:app`

Now that my new application is split into multiple files I used a file `run.py` to start the app, but I'm not sure how I should call Gunicorn now. I've read other questions and tutorials but they haven't worked. When I run `gunicorn run:app` and I try to access the site I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.

I think my problem is more Gunicorn than Nginx or Flask, since the site works if I just type `./run.py`. In any case, I've included my Nginx config and a few other files below. Thanks so much for your help!

File: `run.py`

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
app.run(debug = True, port=8001)
```

File: `app/views.py`

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.id.desc()).all()
    return render_template('index.html', posts=posts)
```

File: `nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com/public_html/app;

    access_log /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log;

    client_max_body_size 2M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @gunicorn_proxy;
    }

    location @gunicorn_proxy {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check that you can access http://127.0.0.1:8001 ? Then - I would change "location @gunicorn_proxy" to "location /" (and comment out previous location section )

Comment: @soerium I can access 127.0.0.1:8001 since when I run my app from the command line, Flask prints `* Running on http://127.0.0.1:8001`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is the development server is running when gunicorn imports `app.py`. You only want that to happen when the file is executed directly (e.g., `python app.py`).

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # You don't need to set the port here unless you don't want to use 5000 for development.
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Once you've made this change, you should be able to run the application with `gunicorn run:app`. Note that gunicorn uses port 8000 by default. If you wish to run on an alternate port (e.g., 8001), you'll need to specify that with `gunicorn -b :8001 run:app`.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I tried changing `run.py` to include the `if` statement you suggest and again it works if I execute it directly from the command like is `$ ./run.py` but not if I try gunicorn `$gunicorn rup:app`.

Comment: whoops, that's a typo. Gunicorn doesn't seem to work when I type `$ gunicorn run:app`.

Comment: I updated my answer to include information about specifying the port.